# ANT return array from bash script

Tags: javascript, string, bash, shell, ant

I'm encountering some problem to execute a bash script from ANT and get a return string value.

Reading abroad, i saw that bash script can only return integer value (related to the error / output code).

So, which best approach to get string as return value of external script execution with ANT ?

Question is justified due to the fact, that we need to perform multiple alteration on string that will be complex to maintain in an ANT script.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Without knowing your use case it's hard to advise more accurately, but it sounds like you may be better off managing a lot more in bash directly with some sort of wrapper script which returns success/failure to ANT.

Comment: Hi jdpjamesp, thansk for answer. Simply task was about a single value calculation based on variables from ANT script. Calc was so hard to port in ANT script so we used exec ant to execute bash script in charge to calculate it. Problem derived from the impossibility of get it as "return value" in the "big ant script".

Comment: Solved it, using a swap way: ANT > bash > [write on file] > ANT > [read from file].